# Android Switch button inside RecyclerView's every item

Tags: android, togglebutton

I am working with **RecyclerView and using Switch component** in every item of it.

```
<Switch
    android:id="@+id/list_item_switch"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/list_item_price"
    android:textOff="@string/switch_save"
    android:textOn="@string/switch_buy" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
    />
```

I am using **setOnCheckedChangeListener** event to listen to state changes

```
holder.mSaveBuySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
            moveItemDialog(pos, isChecked);
        }
    }
});
```

Use of **buttonView.isPressed()** is to identify whether the **setChecked** on Switch is called by User or it is called programmatically by code.

Now it is working perfect When we click on Switch.

**Problem** - How can I make it work when we slide the Switch? in Android 4.0+ Switch component present nice ready made toggle button but I need to know when user slides the switch so that I can execute the same code which is executed when it is pressed. That is,

```
if (buttonView.isPressed()) {
    moveItemDialog(pos, isChecked);
}
```

Thank You.

Comment: what happens when you actually click on Switch? Which kind of problem are you experiencing?

Comment: There is no problem on click, I want to be able to identify slide event as well. buttonView.isPressed works fine but I could not find anything when I slide the switch.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is too old. But I've try with `android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat` it's also works with sliding.

This my sample code and some debug log.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
android:id="@+id/saklar_switch"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Debug Code

```
Log.d("SAKLAR","Pos: "+position+" buttonView.isPressed()"+buttonView.isPressed());
Log.d("SAKLAR","Pos: "+position+" buttonView = isCheccked? "+isChecked);
```

Debug Result

```
Pos: 2 buttonView.isPressed()true
Pos: 2 buttonView = isCheccked? true
```

`isPressed()` debug also return true while I'm sliding the switch button.